# WebSphere: serializable messages in System.out

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

I administer several WebSphere 6.1 servers running the same application in a load balancing configuration.  For one of the servers, the WebSphere System.out file is getting filled with these sorts of messages:

> [6/5/14 20:20:35:602 EDT] 0000000f SessionContex E   Miscellaneous
>   data: Attribute "rotatorFiles" is declared to be serializable but is
>   found to generate exception "java.io.NotSerializableException" with
>   message "com.company.storefront.vo.ImageRotatorItemVO".  Fix the
>   application so that the attribute "rotatorFiles" is correctly
>   serializable at runtime.

The same code is not generating these messages in the other WebSphere servers log files.  I suspect there is some configuration setting that is causing these messages to be logged on one server but not the others.  Does anyone out there know what setting that may be?

Answer (score 0):

At least two come to my mind:

- you may have session replication enabled on that server, check in Application servers > server1 > Session management > Distributed environment settings
- you may have PMI counter that monitors session size (Servlet Session Manager.SessionObjectSize) enabled, check in Application servers > server1 > Performance Monitoring Infrastructure (PMI)

The paths in the console are from v8, so they might be a bit different in v6.1, but you should get the idea.

Comment: One server that isn't doing excessive logging is monitoring the session size, so this can't be it.  I'm thinking this must be some setting within the WebSphere admin console, but I'm baffled as to what it could be.

Comment: Are you sure, it's not the other way around? If that server would monitor session size, it would explain these messages. Did you check class `com.company.storefront.vo.ImageRotatorItemVO` whats not serializable in there?

Comment: That class isn't set up to be serializable, but the other three WAS servers running the same code don't report the "not serializable"  message in the log files.

Comment: Are these servers in cluster? Are the nodes synchronized? Did you check for this server Runtime settings for PMI and Session persistence on the server and application level? Because I see no other reasons for this. Somewhere you are trying to serialize session, which has notserializable attribute. Maybe you have some monitoring tool connected to that server?